# Linux find command - viewing results

Tags: linux

I'm not exprert with shell but I try to use:

```
find / -user test
```

And I got so many results and cannot back to top of the list.
I can see only some last results...

Is any way to view all results or how to sort for reading?

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Barranka This is what i do not like about SO, splitting the community into fragmetns.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy It's not about splitting the community. SO is about programming. Using find is off topic.

Comment: @Matteo You are first person saying on SO that bash is not programming.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy This specific question is not about programming, but about the usage of a very specific command in *nix. As far as I can tell, the OP is not about putting this into a script.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy Not the only one as there are two close votes. Anyway from my experience you can get much better answers on Unix & Linux for shell related question. The vote is not to be unpolite is to help the OP. Here you get programmers with some Unix experience, there you get much better answers for this kind of questions (OK, this one is not so complex but anyway)

Comment: Notice that I'm not saying this question should be scrapped... I'm just saying that it should be migrated to a better suited place within the StackExchange community

Comment: @Barranka How does whether OP puts in a script or using it on command-line matter?

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy My God, man! Give it a break!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find / -user test | less
```

This will pipe to `less` which will allow you to see it page by page.
Another solution is to redirect it into a file, and then view that with an editor!
Like this:

```
find / -user test >> $HOME/findresult.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find / -user test | less
```

That will display one screen at a time, use up & down arrow keys to move one line up or down, use [PgDn] or [PgUp] to navigate one screen down or up, and when you are done, hit [Q] to exit.

---

Just a little geek humor about the `less` and `more` commands:

> “`less` is more, but more `more` than `more` is, so `more` is less `less`, so use more `less` if you want less `more`. (...) If `less` is more than `more`, `most` is more than `less`. "
>
> ([Slackware Linux Essentials](http://slackbook.org/html/file-commands-pagers.html))

---

If you want to learn a bit more about linux, I recommend you [The Low Fat Linux tutorial](http://lowfatlinux.com).

If you are stuck with a command, use `man`. For example:

```
man less
```

will display the help (manual) page for the `less` command.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the good answers by Barranka and Levente, I would like to answer your sort part of the question,

```
find / -user test| sort | less
```

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, specify the type that is being searched
file -f
directory -d

so that number of output results is reduced and easier to skim through or search